# Fill ng-pattern from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object structure like this:

```
var fields = [
  { field: 'test', checks: [
    { check: 'test1' },
    { check: 'test2' },
    { check: 'testn' }
  ] },
  {/* next field */}
];
```

Now I want to check with ng-pattern an input field, where the user can type what ever he want, but just the items in checks are correct.

```
<tr ng-repeat="field in fields">
    <td><%field.field%></td>
    <td>
        <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            ng-model="model"
            ng-pattern="field.checks[0]" /*test1*/
        >
    </td>
</tr>
```

On this way I could check for one item in checks. How can I check for all items, so that there is something like `ng-pattern="test1|test2|testn"`?

Comment: sounds like you want a `<select>` or select type UI replacement

Comment: No, I want an input, because the user should allowed to type what ever he want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-pattern` expression takes any valid regex string -- you could map your checks and join them with regex's OR symbol (`|`), bind that string to a scope variable and use it with your `ng-pattern`. That way your regex will come out like `test1|test2|testn`

[Working Plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/4W9IpBsYoE3wP5GlQjKv/)